# how to split a hex file into two hex files at the first match of certain criteria in perl or just unix scripts

Tags: perl, awk

I have a HEX file containing following, I want to split them into two HEX files based on the address:

file_in.hex
@00000000
00 FC 00 20 89 01 00 00 D9 01 00 00 DB 01 00 00
DD 01 00 00 DF 01 00 00 E1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3 01 00 00
43 00 00 00 10 00 00 20 00 00 00 00
@200005FC
18 FB FF 7F 01 00 00 00
@20000604
00 00 00 00 80 F0 FA 02 80 F0 FA 02 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 FC 02 00 20 64 03 00 20 CC 03 00 20

if the address is equal or greater than @20000000, the rest of the HEX is saved to a second HEX file, so the result should be like this:

file_out1.hex
@00000000
00 FC 00 20 89 01 00 00 D9 01 00 00 DB 01 00 00
DD 01 00 00 DF 01 00 00 E1 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3 01 00 00
43 00 00 00 10 00 00 20 00 00 00 00

file_out2.hex
@200005FC
18 FB FF 7F 01 00 00 00
@20000604
00 00 00 00 80 F0 FA 02 80 F0 FA 02 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 FC 02 00 20 64 03 00 20 CC 03 00 20

I am quite new to perl. Can I use 'split' to do it? or do I have to use a loop to do the job? Is awk or gawk much easier to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty or very perly, but should get the job done.  It does assume the addresses only go up, and are actually in the text file as shown with the `@`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'file_in.hex';
my $output1 = 'file_out1.hex';
my $output2 = 'file_out2.hex';
my $flipped = 0;

open (my $fh, '<', $input);
open (my $oh, '>', $output1);

while(<$fh>){
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ /[@]/ && !$flipped){
    my $numstr = $line;
    chomp $numstr;
    $numstr =~s/[@]//;
    if(hex($numstr) >= 0x20000000){
        $flipped = 1;
        close $oh;
        open ($oh, '>', $output2);
    }
    }

    print $oh $line;

}

close $oh;
close $fh;
```

Comment: Thank you dsolimano. This is exactly what I was thinking about. but I was not sure about the perl syntax. I was in a hurry, so not enough time to do the research. Thanks again.

Comment: I notice that you use hex(), is there a similar function for binary? I could not find anything so far

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483655/how-do-i-convert-a-binary-string-to-a-number-in-perl

Answer (score 0):

give this perl script a go

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


$/ = "20 00 00 00 00";   # set input record separator
my $input = "/path/to/file";
my $i = 0;
open (my $fh, "<", $input);
while (<$fh>){
    my $filename = "$input$i";  #gen new filename
    open (OUT, ">$filename") or die "cannot create file $filename: $!"; #create and write to new file
    print OUT
    $i++;
}
```